# Problemas ao carregar o Rcmdr

Tags: r

Boa noite quando após instalar o pacote Rcmdr, não consigo carregá-lo para usar. Aparece essa mensagem? Alguém sabe me dizer o que posso fazer pfv?

> local({pkg <- select.list(sort(.packages(all.available = TRUE)),graphics=TRUE)
>   + if(nchar(pkg)) library(pkg, character.only=TRUE)})
>   Loading required package: splines
>   Loading required package: RcmdrMisc
>   Loading required package: car
>   Loading required package: carData
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called ‘data.table’
>   Error: package ‘car’ could not be loaded

Comment: A parte relevante é *there is no package called ‘data.table’*. Tem que instalar o pacote `data.table`. Nota: esse pacote tem tido problemas com a última versão do R 3.5.0. Eu tentei [isto](https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg248706.html) e resultou.

Answer (score 1):

Ao instalar um pacote você pode pedir ao R para instar as dependências junto. Por exemplo:

```
install.packages('Rcmdr', dependencies = TRUE)
```

deve resolver o problema.